# Show Views exposed filter user adjustment

Tags: 8, views

I have a view where I show a table of some data. In that view I have a exposed form with some default filter values and the setting of remembering the input.

Now my question is, how can I check if the current filter values are not the default filter values?

I use Drupal 8.